# Emacs background color limited to region

Tags: emacs, background-color, region

I was wondering how I could set the background color for a given region of the emacs frame.

The programming standard I'm following specifies max line width of 80 chars, which sometimes is ignored for convenience and readability. Now, say the frame is of some width greater than 80 chars, it would be very nice if this outside region could have a different background color.

If anyone could assist, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure, but I know the mmm package does colored regions so it might be a good starting bit of code to look at.

Comment: I'm assuming this can be done with overlays in some manner, but I have no clue how to go about it, definitely interested in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already done for you. Read:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EightyColumnRule
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillColumnIndicator
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLinePosition
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindLongLines

and follow links.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. I really though my issue was a special case, and now I feel silly.